# Обрезка double

Tags: c#

Как округлить "DOUBLE" до сотой части, то есть есть значение 3,125694, а надо 3,12?
(Из 3,125694 надо оставить 3,12)

Comment: Если при выводе -- это одно, если во внутреннем представлении -- обломайтесь. Числа представляются в двоичном виде, а 0.01 в двоичном представлении -- периодическая дробь. При ограниченной длине мантиссы  точно не представляется.

Comment: Число 3,12 в двоичном виде точно не представляется?

Comment: @Чад Это 3 целых и 3/25. Не должно. Вывод gdb (насчёт порядка байт -- лень и думать, и смотреть):

     $1 = {0xf6, 0x28, 0x5c, 0x8f, 0xc2, 0xf5, 0x8, 0x40}

Непериодические дроби  -- те, у кого знаменатель -- степень двойки.

Comment: Таки в переводе в десятичную систему же периодичность уходит... Таки не совсем понимаю почему нельзя внутреннее представление обрезать? Даже с сохранением той же самой переодичности... У нас в принципе все числа переодичные, просто принято считать что 2,(9)==2,(0)==2 для удобства человека.

Comment: Точнее 1.(9)==2.(0)==2

Answer (score 6):

```
double k = 3.1545421;
k = Math.Round(k, 2); // 2-количество знаков после запятой
Text = k.ToString();
```